# how an rest API can be called after 2 days in java

Tags: spring, rest, api

I have a rest API (implemented in spring) and I want to call it in Timekeeper (banking domain). The user will set time at TimeKeeper  suppose use set time (2 hour and 30 min.) Bank working hour 10AM-4PM.

This API will be called according to the following conditions:

-> if 2.30 hour comes before bank working hour then my API will be called after 2.30 hour or next day after same time. Suppose current time is 12AM user give 2 hour.. then 12+3= 3pm.. it comes in bank working hour then My API will be called after 3 hour from current hour.

-> if user gives 5 hours and  current time is 3 pm; it exceeds bank working hour so my API will be called next day after 4 hours means next day at 2 pm working hour is (10 am -4 pm)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly. As is, it looks a lot like you just want us to do your work.

Answer (score 0):

For all cron jobs you can use java quartz library a quick doc is [here](https://www.baeldung.com/quartz)
and  [official link](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)